# Позиционирование в CSS

Tags: css, позиционирование

В чем разница между `position: relative` и `position: absolute`?

Comment: relative - элемент относительно которого будет происходить позиционирование абсолютного элемента

Comment: Между relative и absolute вообще ничего общего, читайте документацию/учебники css и используйте каждый position там, где это уместно для решаемой задачи

Comment: мое мнение: position: relative в основном используется в связке с position: absolute, так как "дырка" (место, которое забито под элемент, а элемента там нет) в документе не нужна. то есть, берем блок 1 и задаем ему position: relative, top:0, left:0 , а его потомку / дочернему блоку 2 задаем position: absolute с нужными top и left и позиционируем относительно блока 1 (если для блока 2 нет более близкого предка с position, который не равен static)

Answer (score 0):

1. *position: relative* в основном используется в связке с *position: absolute*, так как "дырка" (место, которое забито под элемент, а элемента там нет) в документе не нужна.
2. то есть, берем блок 1 и задаем ему *position: relative, top:0, left:0* , а его потомку / дочернему блоку 2 задаем *position: absolute* с нужными *top* и *left* и позиционируем относительно блока 1 (если для блока 2 нет более близкого предка с *position*, который не равен *static*)

Если не прав, поправьте

Comment: Это одно из популярных применений, но, во-первых, это работает не только с relative, а во-вторых, это вообще эталонный костыль)

Comment: это работает не только с relative, я согласен. ищется предок с position, который не равен static и от него идет отсчет, например, top и left

Answer (score -1):

В зависимости от ситуации. DOM элемент спозиционированный с помощью absolute не влияет на расположение остальных блоков, а вот relative влияет. Пример 
    codepen.io/gazelyk/pen/wYzpad